# How do we analyze curl loader results?

Tags: performance, curl, benchmarking, ftps

The ftps.txt (output from curl-loader) file seems a lot confusing. How do we measure through put.

Can some one guide me in these lines. Here is the sample output:
RunTime(sec),Appl,Clients,Req,1xx,2xx,3xx,4xx,5xx,Err,T-Err,D,D-2xx,Ti,To
0, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
3, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
3, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
6, H/F   , 10, 73, 0, 63, 10, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1017, 1037, 1906544, 985
6, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
9, H/F   , 10, 27, 0, 27, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1391, 1391, 8356700, 855
9, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
12, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10711549, 0
12, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
15, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9058033, 0
15, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
18, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11273484, 0
18, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
21, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13058480, 0
21, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
24, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13299085, 0
24, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
27, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13314650, 0
27, H/F/S , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
30, H/F   , 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13258944, 0

Answer (score 0):

read [manual](http://curl-loader.sourceforge.net/doc/faq.html%22)

Currently HTTP/HTTPS statistics includes the following counters:

- run-time in seconds;
- List item
- requests num;
- 1xx success num;
- 2xx success num;
- 3xx redirects num;
- client 4xx errors num;
- server 5xx errors num;
- other errors num, like resolving, tcp-connect, server closing or empty responses number **(Err)**;
- url completion time expiration errors **(T-Err)**;
- average application server Delay (msec), estimated as the time between HTTP request and HTTP response without taking into the account network latency (RTT) **(D)**;
- average application server Delay for 2xx (success) HTTP-responses, as above, but only for 2xx responses. The motivation for that is that 3xx redirections and 5xx server errors/rejects may not necessarily provide a true indication of a testing server working functionality **(D-2xx)**;
- throughput in, batch average, Bytes/sec **(T-In)**;
- throughput out, batch average, Bytes/sec **(T-Out)**;